# Yii2 Linkpager can pagination like this

Tags: yii2

How can I pagination like this with yii 2 framework, demo on page https://laravel-tricks.com/

[image]

resource: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to have a `...` pseudo button? And the last page? Or what do you want? Please describe your needs and don't let the reader puzzle...

Answer (score 0):

This is easy just increase number of maxButtonCount. Here is example:

This is GridView.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'pager' => [
            'maxButtonCount'=>40,    // Set maximum number of page buttons that can be displayed
        ],
        'columns' => [ ....
```

These is LinkPager.

```
echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pagination,
    'maxButtonCount'=>40, 
    .....
]);
```